# MySQL trigger conditional logic has unexpected behavior

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm having issues using MySQL triggers to keep item counts as users add or remove them. We have two basic tables with following columns:
user_data

- user_id - `UNSIGNED` `INT(11)` `PRIMARY KEY` `AI`
- item_count - `UNSIGNED` `INT(11)`

item_data

- item_id - `UNSIGNED` `INT(11)` `PRIMARY KEY` `AI`
- user_id - `UNSIGNED` `INT(11)` `FK(user_data.user_id)`
- version_id - `UNSIGNED` `INT(11)`
- type - `VARCHAR(32)`
- active - `TINYINT`

The tables above have more columns, but they're not relevant to the problem. Upon `UPDATE` and `INSERT` events `user_data.item_count` should be updated accordingly. I therefore have the following trigger setup 
The insert trigger looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertItem 
AFTER INSERT ON `item_data`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF( NEW.`type` = 'inStock') THEN
        UPDATE `user_data`
        SET `item_count` = `item_count` + 1
        WHERE `user_id` = NEW.`user_id`;
    END IF;
END;
```

The update trigger looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateItem 
AFTER UPDATE ON `item_data`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.`type` = 'inStock') THEN
        IF OLD.`active` = 1 AND NEW.`active` = 0 THEN
            SET @change = -1;
        ELSEIF OLD.`active` = 0 AND NEW.`active` = 1 THEN
            SET @change = 1;
        END IF;
        IF @change IS NOT NULL THEN
            UPDATE `user_data`
            SET `item_count` = `item_count` + @change
            WHERE `user_id` = NEW.`user_id`;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
```

The problem arises when I run a maintenance script that updates parameters seemingly unrelated to the triggers. I get the error:

```
SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 
1690 BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in
'(`user_data`.`item_count` + (@`change`))' 
(SQL: update `item_data` set `version_id` = 397928 where `item_id` = 159186)
```

This clearly arises when a negative change occurs on an item where `user_data.item_count = 0`,
but how can simply updating the `version_id` trigger this change given the definition of my triggers, and why is the change negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@change` preserves the value in active session, you must reset that value at begin of trigger:

```
...
BEGIN
    SET @change = null;

...
```